# How can I reveal/hide images that I can interact with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a website where I'm looking to hide things like images, links, or any interactive element, that upon hover reveal those things.

I currently have this mockup where I have two images overlaying each other and when you scroll around, reveal the background image with text in it. How might I add elements to the div being revealed that I can interact with?

**UPDATE:**

I've gotten a little further with putting an element being hidden by the circle element, but still am unable to make the element self constrained and contained to the size of the background. I've tried resizing its height and width properties, but still can't get it to position properly within.

```
    (function ($) {
     "use strict";
        
        $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
            $(".circle" ).animate({
                top: event.pageY-($(".circle").height()/2),
                left: event.pageX-($(".circle").width()/2)
            }, 0, "linear");
        });
        
    })(jQuery)
    body, html{
    background-image: url();
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    cursor: none;
}

.hide{
  opacity:0;
  color:orange;
  font-size:200px;
}

.tada {
  height: 110px;
  width: 540px;
  top: 131px;
  left: 368px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;/* so you can tell if you actually click it */
  z-index: 50;
}


#BG{
      background-image: url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2904/14648139676_6a96f5fc58_h.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    cursor: none;
}
.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

}


.circle{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    
    background-image: url(http://dailyrindblog.com/PeterLum/test.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;    
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#item{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}

.circle.full{
  width: 1000%;
  height: 1000%;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
}


.treasure{
        background-image: url(http://dailyrindblog.com/PeterLum/circle.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size: 250px 250px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px;
    padding: 0;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin: 0;
   cursor:pointer;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 50%;

}
    <div id="BG">
    <div class="circle">
    <div class="overlay">
    <a href="www.google.com"><div class="treasure"></div></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please place all relevant code in the question, ideally in a snippet. You can use the `[<>]` button in the editor to create one.

Comment: why not use the hidden tag in html? <p hidden>Hidden paragraph.</p>

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is going to sound a little weird and I might take a while of time, but I think this could work.

All of the text appears within `.circle` including the "text" for links. Then, use `pointer-events: none` on `.circle`.

Position links and such absolutely, and when you click on it, ta da!

(I'm hoping this makes sense. For example...)

```js
(function ($) {
 "use strict";
    
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        $(".circle" ).animate({
            top: event.pageY-($(".circle").height()/2),
            left: event.pageX-($(".circle").width()/2)
        }, 0, "linear");
    });
    
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.tada {
  height: 110px;
  width: 540px;
  top: 131px;
  left: 368px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;/* so you can tell if you actually click it */
  z-index: 50;
}

body, html{
    background-image: url();
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 900px;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    cursor: none;
}

#BG{
      background-image: url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2904/14648139676_6a96f5fc58_h.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    cursor: none;
}

.overlay{
   /* background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);*/
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


.circle{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    
    background-image: url(http://dailyrindblog.com/PeterLum/test.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;    
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#item{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}

.circle.full{
  width: 1000%;
  height: 1000%;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="BG">
     <div class="circle">

      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
  
  <a class="tada" href="https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/3jbf7562/"></a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is cool Chris! However, I'm trying to have elements that can be visually revealed by the circle itself. I feel like I might need to append elements to the circle div's layer somehow.